# bipartite graph--Sellers and Buyers

Tags: algorithm, graph, dynamic-programming

Given several sellers and buyers, each seller has an amount of products, each buyer wants to buy several products from sellers. Some sellers can not transact with some buyers, if a buyer can not get enough products as he wants, the transaction will not succeed. If we know there is one strategy that can satisfy all buyers, how to find this strategy?

I draw a graph to illustrate the problem, this is just an example. The question wants you to provide a transaction strategy for each buyer so that all buyers can get enough products they want.
[seller buyer example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrxkH.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume one buyer may buy multiple things from one seller. It is not hard to change it to one item.

This can be solved by maximum flow algorithm. Direct edges from buyer to their connected sellers. Assign capacity b_i for those edges. B_i is the amount the buyer needs. Add two nodes S,T. Add edges from S to all buyers. Assign capacity b_i to each of those edges. B_i is again the amount the buyer i needs. Add edges from every seller vertex to T. Assign capacity S_i to those edges. S_i is the amount the seller i has. Find the maximum flow from S to T. If it is equal to the sum of all buyers required amounts then there is a solution to the problem and it can be found by the amount of flow which goes through every edge from buyers to sellers (this is a follow up of integral flow theorem).

Comment: Hi Saeed, thank you so much for your excellent solution. sorry I didnt describe the problem clearly. Initially, you do not know if all buyers can be satisfied and you are asked to satisfy as many buyers as possible and each buyer can buy products from several sellers. Your solution is great, but if you set the edge capacity to be s_i for all edges going in seller i, the total sum of seller i  may be exceeded, right ?

Comment: And since you cannot satisfy a buyer with products less than his requirement, if I use max flow theory, even though I can get the maximum flow, but I still can not get the number of satisfied buyers (if we dont know all buyers can be satisfied and we want to find the max number of satisfied buyers).

Comment: @AvocadoAushi, 1. total sum of seller i won't exceed S_i, because it's outgoing edge has capacity S_i and cannot carry more flows. 2. I answered the question which you asked. What you explain right now is different situation, but I'll think about it, and you can turn it to a new question.

Comment: Get it. Thanks a lot, I'll post another new question. For this question, if there exists a perfect solution, max flow algorithm can find the strategy. I'' try using Ford-Fulkerson and maxflow-mincut to solve this problem~~

Comment: @AvocadoAushi, you can mark this answer as an accepted answer by turning the tick mark (in the left side of the answer) to green.

Comment: @AvocadoAushi, About your second problem I guess it is npc, I'm not sure though you can ask it. Maybe a modification to this algorithm works, but usually all or nothing flow type questions are NPC.

Comment: I see~~If this is npc, I will not be able to get the best answer in such cases, am I correct? If it is true, max flow min cut can get the best solution when there exists a perfect solution but if not, it can only provide a solution which might not be the best solution. I have posted it in a new problem, here is the link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573685/sellers-and-buyers

Comment: @AvocadoAushi, That's true, but it is maybe very well known polynomial problem, I didn't think about it well.